# Cannot get length of file object in react from input type file

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have a function that fires and receives the e.target.files object but I cannot get the length of it. console.log(e.target.files.length) does not even fire.

```
<input multiple onChange={(e) => { this.handlefileupload(e) }} type="file" id="file" style={{ display: "none" }} />

this.handlefileupload = (e) => {
    console.log(e.target.files)
    console.log(e.target.files.length)


}
```

console.log(e.target.files) gives:

```
FileList {0: File(7105138), 1: File(7105138), 2: File(16792776), length: 3}0: File(7105138) {name: "image1.jpg", lastModified: 1544552208803, lastModifiedDate: Tue Dec 11 2018 10:16:48 GMT-0800 (Pacific Standard Time), webkitRelativePath: "", size: 7105138, …}1: File(7105138) {name: "imge2.jpg", lastModified: 1544468259102, lastModifiedDate: Mon Dec 10 2018 10:57:39 GMT-0800 (Pacific Standard Time), webkitRelativePath: "", size: 7105138, …}2: File(16792776) {name: "image3.png", lastModified: 1544558528903, lastModifiedDate: Tue Dec 11 2018 12:02:08 GMT-0800 (Pacific Standard Time), webkitRelativePath: "", size: 16792776, …}length: 3__proto__: FileList
```

[Snapshot of console.log(e.target.files) as requested](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HcRNh.png)

Comment: what happens you console.log the length? `FileList` should have a `length` attribute

Comment: I guess `e.target.files.FileList.length` would give you length.

Comment: It does not work

Comment: Can you upload the chrome dev tools snapshot with expanded `e.target.files` result? Hope that would give a clear picture.

Comment: @DanielVeinberg does  `console.log(e.target.files.length)`. run if you delete the first console.log?

Comment: No it does not run

Answer (score 1):

I run a sample similar to your code, it seems like nothing is broken and actually I could get the length.

https://codesandbox.io/s/0m087x84vw

You might need to provide more code to help us detect where is the problem

Answer (score -1):

It looks like you might of meant to type `console.log(e.target.files.FileList.length)` .

Comment: I think that `FileList` is the type of `files` as chrome prints it in the console, not an attribute on `files`